# Cannot get past 401 error OAuth with Desk.com

Tags: c#, oauth

I've been working on this for days now trying to get this auth to work with Desk.com's API http://dev.desk.com/.  I've even tried using a framework forked out there such as https://github.com/buildmaster/oauth-mvc.net#readme but I still get 401 errors...I can never auth.

I can't go another day with this not working..and have spent a few days on this already..This is all my custom code here that I've been beating my brains trying to figure out why Desk.com is rejecting my first attempt to make an API call here to them.

Desk.com says it's got to be my signature, but I've checked my signature over and over again and I feel the signature isn't the problem.  I even tried using oauth-mvc.net and used their utilities to create my signature (https://github.com/buildmaster/oauth-mvc.net#readme) and I still get a 401 back when using the sig creation with that framework.  So I can't be sure it's the signature, it's gotta be something simple stupid either in how I form the request..I'm not sure.

So here's my code..I cannot see for the life of me what is wrong.  Just follow it down, it's as if you're debugging with me. (FYI if you can't see it, right click the image and choose to view it to see the full pic).

1_UnitTestStart.jpg
[image]
2_AboutToCreateSignature.jpg
[image]
2_AboutToCreateSignature_2.jpg
[image]
3_AboutToCreateSignatureBase.jpg
[image]
4_AboutToEncodeEachKeyAndValue.jpg
[image]
6_AboutToSortEncodedParamList.jpg
[image]
7_ParamListIsSorted.jpg
[image]
8_AboutToNormalizeTheSortedParamList.jpg
[image]
9_SortedParamListIsNowNormalized.jpg
[image]
10_ShowingMyUrlEncodeMethodHere.jpg
[image]
11_BaseSignatureStringCreated.jpg
[image]
12_SigningTheHMACSHA1.jpg
[image]
13_ConvertingToHash.jpg
[image]
14_Hashed.jpg
[image]
15_ReturnFinalSignature.jpg
[image]
16_AboutToGetAuthHeaderParamsNormalizedForRequestHeader.jpg
[image]
16_AboutToGetAuthHeaderParamsNormalizedForRequestHeader_2.jpg
[image]
17_ParamsAreNormalizedForRequestHeader.jpg
[image]
18_AboutToSendAPIRequestToGetAllCases.jpg
[image]
19_AboutToCreateTheHttpWebRequest.jpg
[image]
20_AboutToAddHeadersToRequest.jpg
[image]
20_AboutToAddHeadersToRequest_2.jpg
[image]
21_AboutToSendTheRequest.jpg
[image]
22_ViewOfRequestInfoBeforeSending.jpg
[image]
23_Response401Error.jpg
[image]
24_Fiddler_RequestDetails.jpg
[image]
24_Fiddler_RequestDetails_2.jpg
[image]
24_Fiddler_RequestDetails_3.jpg
[image]
24_Fiddler_RequestDetails_4.jpg
[image]

Comment: what the hell?  Who voted to close this and why

Comment: I dont think that it should be closed. but in my opinion, it is not well written question because of the images. as they stand, they are not readable(ok, you can zoom, but I dont think that people will bother)

Comment: yea the thing is, I'd have to write too much and pictures of this will speed things up and make it more clear in this case.  OAuth is complex...so it's not something I want to ramble on, I want to show the code that's not working.

Comment: it's like you give too little of info or too much.  I'd think having the screen shots of code here in this complex case would be a helpers dream.

Comment: All we need when debugging an invalid signature are 3 things. Your signature base, your code used to hmac sign, and the output from fiddler of the request/response. I would recommend cleaning up this question using that format.

Answer (score 0):

99% of the time, an invalid signature means there is an issue with your signature base string. Have your code always log this value because you are going to need at some point or another...

It looks like your base signature string doesn't contain the oauth_version param. Your signature base should contain all paramters starting with oauth_ and any query string params(but it doesn't look like you are sending anything in the qs).

Comment: I've actually tried adding backin the version, no luck.  For this call, I am performing a GET to get a list of customers or cases...stuff like this...just getting a bunch of records.  For this API there are no required params to do this.  I am just hitting the resourceName.json endpoint...so that's why I have no querystrings.  Also I'm using the HttpRequestHeader for sending stuff, I dno't want to go the route of using querystrings even if I have to send data.  It's just recommended to use the Header instead of querystring and to me it's cleaner also.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather late answer, but in case anyone else is having problems, it may help out.

You can use RestSharp to simplify working with the desk.com API. I had some problems getting OAuth to work at first, but after adding RestSharp to the project, things became a whole lot simpler. I have put together a small SDK for this. It is far from done, but you can grab the source code and see how the connection is established:

http://danielsaidi.github.com/desk-csharp-sdk/